# Jenkins - Promoted Builds in Pipeline, configuring parameters in promotion action

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, pipeline, build-pipeline-plugin

When I set up a *Project A* which triggers *Project B* (with Parameters) and *Project B* triggers now *Project C1* and *C2* the whole chain (with parameters) shows up neatly in the Build Pipeline view of Jenkins:

[image: Screenshot: Build Pipeline]

However I have added a *Promoted Build* setting on *Project B* which tracks completion of *C1* **and** *C2*.

[image: Promotion Action of Project B]

There are now 3 problems with this:

a) A minor thing, but I really wondered if I am doing something wrong as it seems to be an essential functionality to me: the promotion (stars) are not visible in the Build Pipeline view.

b) What is worse, I set up the promotion action (of *B*) to trigger a new Job *D*. This works, however I cannot pass the build parameters of Job *B* along (D receives unexpanded value `${iso.name}`).

c) The *Project D* Job triggered by the promotion runs and shows that it was triggered by *B*, I also see in the Promotion log of *B* that it triggered it. But it does not show in the Build Pipeline View, is there a way to get it added (it generally does not show up as a downstream build). Would it help to actually share a fingerprinted artifact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) Build pipeline does not have the functionality to show promotion stars in it.

b) The way you have passed the parameters are correct. It should work when you use the ${iso.name} on build steps. **But if you use this in a 'Execute batch command step' It will not work**. You will have to use %iso.name% on a batch command.

c)Builds that are triggered by promotion is not visible because it's a bug in the build pipeline plugin. https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-22203

Comment: a) do you think it makes sense to open a bug for it? b) The trigger build with parameters works, but not for the promotion process (it actually does work but the parameters for the (past) build on which the promotion is executed are not set. c) thanks!

Comment: @eckes It's good to open a bug. It's a missing feature actually.